# How to display zero values in the legend of PlotALot graph based on RSForm Pro results?

Tags: administrator, rsform

In the backend, I am compiling some survey results generated from RSForm Pro and I want to display the statistics graphically using a PlotALot pie chart.

My form has 4 possible values for this particular question: `Australia`, `NewZealand`, `Oceania`, and `Other`.

I started with the following query in the sql textarea of the Plot1 tab:

```
SELECT FieldValue, COUNT(1)
FROM jprefix_rsform_submission_values
WHERE FormId = 8
  AND FieldName = 'Location'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

However, this omits any location that has a count of zero.  To ensure that all possible locations were included, I derived a table of default locations via a subquery, then joined the RSForm data to the derived table.

```
SELECT 
    Location,
    COUNT(FieldValue)
FROM (
    (SELECT 'Australia' AS Location)
    UNION
    (SELECT 'New Zealand')
    UNION
    (SELECT 'Oceania')
    UNION
    (SELECT 'Other')) AS defaults
LEFT JOIN jprefix_rsform_submission_values
    ON FormId = 8
       AND FieldName = 'Location'
       AND FieldValue = REPLACE(Location, ' ', '')
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

This now provides the correct result set:

```
Location    |  COUNT(FieldValue)
--------------------------------
Australia   |       46
Other       |        7
New Zealand |        0
Oceania     |        0
```

The trouble is, when I feed this sql to PlotAlot, I only see:

[image]

How can I prevent PlotAlot from omitting the zero values in the legend?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this by amending the second column in the SELECT clause to generate a minuscule, non-zero decimal value.

```
IF(COUNT(FieldValue) > 0, COUNT(FieldValue), 0.1)
```

For the record, `GREATEST(COUNT(FieldValue), 0.1)` will have virtually the same result set (technically, all of the results become float values) and the graphic output is the same.

As a result, the Locations appear in the legend and the `0.1` values are rounded to `0`.

[image]

---

As a potentially related issue dealing with small values being lumped together into an "Other" label in the legend, it might be solvable by setting the [sliceVisibilityThreshold](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#slice-visibility-threshold) value to `0`.

To implement this, go to PlotALot's chart editor, click the Extra tab and inside of the Extra Options field, enter `sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0`.